# Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using a sealed class to return data from network. but when i am building the project i am getting the following error

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  error(errorMessage: String, error: Throwable): State
>   Please specify it explicitly.

What am i missing here?

Here is the code

```
suspend fun getdataFromApi(context: Context?, token: String?): State<ScheduleReminderListResponse> =
    withContext(schedulerProvider.io)
    {

            try {
                val list = network.getScheduleReminderList(token).await()
                schedeleReminderListLocalDao.insertAll(list)
                return@withContext State.success(list)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                return@withContext State.error( e.message ?: "Unknown Error",  e  )
            }


        }






sealed class State<T> {

class Loading<T>: State<T>()
data class Error<T>(val errorMessage: String?, val error: Throwable): State<T>()
data class Success<T>(var data: T) : State<T>()

companion object {
    fun <T> loading(): State<T> =
        Loading()

    fun <T> error(errorMessage: String, error: Throwable): State<T> =
        Error(errorMessage, error)

    fun <T> success(data: T): State<T> =
        Success(data)

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this line `State.error( e.message ?: "Unknown Error",  e  )` the compiler does not know what `T` should be. If you compare it with `success`, you will see that you explicitly provide an argument of `T` which the compiler uses to infer the type. 
You can specify it like this when calling error:

```
State.error<TYPE_OF_SCHEDULE_REMINDER_LIST>( e.message ?: "Unknown Error",  e  )
```

Since you're not using `T` in `Error`, you probably want to consider removing it entirely from the sealed class and only use it where it makes sense.

```
sealed class State {

    object Loading : State()
    data class Error(val errorMessage: String?, val error: Throwable) : State()
    data class Success<T>(var data: T) : State()

    companion object {
        fun loading(): State = Loading

        fun error(errorMessage: String, error: Throwable): Error =
            Error(errorMessage, error)

        fun <T> success(data: T): Success<T> = Success(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Error` data class defines the `T` type parameter but does not use it in any way. Therefore, when you create an `Error` instance, there is no way for the compiler to infer what type should be used for T.

To fix this, change the definition of `State` and `Error` so that they don't have a type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In oposition to [@s1m0nw1 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56770815/4758618), if you want to keep the type parameter in the `State` model (so that return values are nice looking and type-safe) you could consider marking `T` as `out` and use `Nothing` in sub-classes that do not use it

```
sealed class State<out T> {

    object Loading: State<Nothing>()
    data class Error(val errorMessage: String?, val error: Throwable): State<Nothing>()
    data class Success<T>(var data: T): State<T>()

    companion object {
        fun <T> loading(): State<T> = Loading

        fun <T> error(errorMessage: String, error: Throwable): State<T> = Error(errorMessage, error)

        fun <T> success(data: T): State<T> = Success(data)
    }
}
```

that way your example method will stay the same nad you do not need to perform unsafe casts

Comment: As an additional benefit, you may try to skip the companion object and use constructors directly